# AEM Sightly - passing a variable to JS

Tags: aem, sightly

I'd like to pass a value into my JS via Sightly.

Something like this:

```
<div data-sly-use.test="'test.js' @ value='${v}'">
```

But the syntax is wrong?

This is obviously wrong too:

```
<div data-sly-use.test="'${test.js' @ value='${v}'}">
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

As explained on this sightly page, you need to pass value inside ${}.
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/aem/6-1/develop/sightly/use-api-in-javascript.html

Try this:

```
<div data-sly-use.test="${'test.js' @ value=v}">
```